# moving from asynchronous to synchronous

Tags: javascript

I have this little sample structure code:

```
function SingleProcess() 
{
    var value1  = item[idx].getAttribute("value1");
    var value2  = item[idx].getAttribute("value2");
    var value3  = item[idx].getAttribute("value3");

    idx -= step;

    return; 
}

function timedChunk(process) 
{
    setTimeout(function() 
    {

        do {
            process.call();
        } while (idx > 0 && (+new Date() - start < 50));

        if (idx > 0) 
        {
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 25);
        }

        if (idx == 0) 
        {
            [...]

            EndProcessing();
        }

    }, 25);
}


$(window).load(function() {
{
    [...]
    idx= 0,

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) 
    {
        [...]

        timedChunk(SingleProcess);

    }
});
```

where before I hadn't the for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) thing so the timedChunk call was always done only once a time. Now I need to do multiple timedChunk for each item in the array items... Is there a way to make timedChunk remaining in the process till (idx==0) then working with next item without re-implementing completely the contents of these functions?...

Thanks in advance!!

Cheers,
Luigi

Comment: `setTimeout(arguments.callee, 25);` this looks worrying. `arguments.callee` is not part of the ES5 spec. If you want to synchronize asynchronous processed I would recommend you have a look at Promises. Most popular frameworks have an implementation.

Comment: HI Frits van Campen, first thanks for your answer but this code was implemented following the timed array processing like in this article: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/08/11/timed-array-processing-in-javascript/ from my previous maintainer of this software but now I need just to transform it as synchronous otherwise if I call timedChunk in the for () it would just cycle to next item so first one wouldn't be really processed..
So is there a possible way to make it synchronous with a minimal implementation just to avoid to ruin the code running inside SingleProcess..? Thanks

Comment: To be honest I don't really understand your question. If you want to remove the asynchronousness just remove `setTimeout` calls.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Javascript, that is not possible. setTimeout and setInterval are asynchronous. And Javascript don't have a real sleep() function so you can't rebuild a synchronous setTimeout without busy waiting!

### Busy waiting

First of all, **don't use it**. Busy waiting means you let the programm do something useless until the time you want to wait is over. In this time a browser would freeze.

Wehn working with async Javascript functions you have to rethink the logic. Javascript is singlethreaded event-driven. It is not like other languages where you can wait for the threadend.

I suggest to rethink your problem and try to solve it event-driven (means use call backs for stuff that must be executed in a specific order)

Comment: callbacks are a poor man's Promise. Promises are designed to synchronizes asynchronous events.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Didn't know yet Promises. Look interesting. But still you work with callbacks. When I see that right you can use $.when like thread.wait in other languages: `$.when($.get("/myAjaxData")).then(function() { alert("the Ajax Request is done!") });` Thats nice!

Comment: Yes, but the callback is attached to the Promise object, and not passed as an argument to the asynchronous function. It's a lot nicer, conceptually.

Comment: Hello, would that mean with Promises I can do something like: $.when( function() { timedChunk(SingleProcess) }).then( function() { $.("#notify").html(" single timedChunk done! ") }); so in this way it would wait till timedChunk is finished inside, right?

Comment: @Luigino You have to do some tests. Take a look at: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/2/8/fun-with-jquery-deferred that could help